# Why isn't Number.toString() being called on a string concatenation operation?

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

While experimenting with the default behavior of the `Object.toString()` function, I noticed that string concatenations like the one below predictably call `toString()` on the target objects:

```
var x = { toString: () => "one" };
var y = { toString: () => "two" };
var output = 'x is ' + x + ' while y is ' + y;
console.log(output); // writes "x is one while y is two" to the console
```

However, the same is not observed when `toString()` is overridden in the prototypes of `Number` and `Boolean`, for instance. It's necessary to "force" a `toString()` call in order to get the desired output:

```
Number.prototype.toString = () => "42";
Boolean.prototype.toString = () => "whatever you wish";

var a = 1;
console.log('The answer is ' + a); // writes "The answer is 1"
console.log('The answer is ' + a.toString()); // writes "The answer is 42"

var b = true;
console.log('Girl you know it\'s ' + b); // writes "Girl you know it's true"
console.log('Girl you know it\'s ' + b.toString()); // writes "Girl you know it's whatever you wish"
```

This is consistent across browsers (tested on Chrome, Firefox and Edge) so I presume it's standard behavior. Where is it documented? Is there a list of the standard objects that get special treatment during string concatenations?

Comment: I am moderately surprised that this behavior still happens with `new Number(1)` rather than `1`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes me too, the `toString` method does not seem to be called in any case besides explicitly.

Comment: I'd be surprised, too, but I made sure that `(1).__proto__` returns `Number`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript will freely convert between number primitives and Number Objects.

If you look at the [rules for the `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) you will see that it says:

> 7 Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).

and

> 9 Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).

So when dealing with `+` it will try to work with primitives over objects.

It then has the [ToString rule](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring) to convert the primitive to a string.

> Number    See 7.1.12.1.

… which then describes [a long special case](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type).

---

In short:

It converts the value to a primitive and then has special case rules for converting numbers to strings.

This means it doesn't treat it as an Object or call the `.toString` method that could normally override such rules.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Plus semantics](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

   - If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then

     - Let lstr be ? ToString(lprim).
     - Let rstr be ? ToString(rprim).
     - Return the string-concatenation of lstr and rstr.
2. [ToString](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tostring)

   Argument type: Number => Return NumberToString(argument).
3. [NumberToString](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type)

   - If m is NaN, return the String "NaN".
   - If m is +0 or -0, return the String "0".
   - If m is less than zero, return the string-concatenation of "-" and ! ToString(-m).
   - If m is +∞, return the String "Infinity".
   - ... You get the idea.